# how to create button in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d, In that I want to create a button, by touching the same some events should be generated.

But I don't know how to make a button in the same. As well as want to save username also. But I am not able to create a text box even.

If any one know, kindly help to create both of the things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not wrong then there is not any method which will create button something like our normal iphone codes.

For cocos2d, making some functions which will work as Buttons, we are suppose to create CCMenuItem. The menu items are the best way to create button and it is easy to be managed.

After a long time I just come to know these things.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked through the Cocos2D [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/)/[forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums) and examples provided in the download package?  There are many example apps which use some sort of menu/buttons.